# I can't use v-bind click inside v-for

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm using VueJS framework v-for. I had lists of items needed to be loop. Each item index will represent a variable to be assign to. The v-bind click wasn't attach onto the element inside the v-for element. I had used computed property but no luck.

**HTML**

```
<a v-for="(ind,s) in sliderItems" id="con-radio{{ind+1}}"
   href="#" @click="sliderRadio = 'con-radio$ind+1'"
   style="width: 100%;height: 100%;">
   <figure class="sf{{ind+1}}"></figure>
</a>
```

**JS**

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    sliderRadio: 'con-radio2', //initial
    sliderData: sliderData

  },
  methods:{

  },
  computed: {
     sliderItems: function() { 
       return this.sliderData;
    }
  }
})
```

**Output**

```
<a href="#" style="width: 100%;height: 100%;" id="con-radio1">
  <figure class="sf1"></figure>
</a>
<a href="#" style="width: 100%;height: 100%;" id="con-radio2">
  <figure class="sf2"></figure>
</a>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to construct new `sliderRadio` value in click handler you need to use string concatenation like this:

```
@click="sliderRadio = 'con-radio' + (ind + 1)"
```